# Isolate Hotspot Users from Private LAN access -mikrotik؟

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding, mikrotik

I am new to mikrotik , i have installed routerboard :

modem IP : 192.168.1.1 ====> to mikrotik port 1

mikrotik IP 192.168.1.10 gateway :192.168.1.1

bridge ports 2,3,4,5, as OUT port

Hotspot created :ip 10.10.10.1 pool : 10.10.10.0/24

Acess point 2 ===> to mikrotik port 2

Acess point 3 ===> to mikrotik port 3

Acess point 4 ===> to mikrotik port 4

Acess point 5 ===> to mikrotik port 5

everything is working fine but ,now if hotspot user is connected to the hotspot, he is able to login to any devices with 192.168.1.0

how to isolate bridge ports(hotspot) from Private network (IN ) with allowing hotspot users to be connected to the internet only not the internal network .

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would first update the Mickrotek firmware because of recent reports of bot router take overs for Ddos and other  malware.  If your hotspot is for guests then this should not be used if router does not offer Vlan or  segmented options

Comment: I already updated to latest . this is hotspot for employees in the company . i dont want to use vlan cause all access points and switch do not support vlans . all what i need is preventing hotspot users to see only 10.10.10.0 IPs and not anything else